# Lebesgue integral minus Lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a [Lebesgue integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) function over $[0,1]$ and $0 \leq a\leq b\leq 1$. Is it true that $$\int_{[0,a]}fd\lambda-\int_{[0,b]}fd\lambda=-\int_{[a,b]}fd\lambda?$$

---

For [Riemann integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral), it is true, but is it true also for Lebesgue Integrals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. By definition,
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,a]}fd\lambda-\int_{[0,b]}fd\lambda
&=\int_{[0,1]}f\,1_{[0,a]}\,d\lambda-\int_{[0,1]}f\,1_{[0,b]}d\lambda=\int_{[0,1]}f\,\big(1_{[0,a]}-1_{[0,b]}\big)\,d\lambda\\[0.3cm]
&=-\int_{[0,1]}f\,1_{[a,b]}\,d\lambda=-\int_{[a,b]}fd\lambda.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Yes. A conceptually slick way to "see" this is that the map
$$
\mu: A\mapsto \int_Af\;d\lambda
$$
defines a [signed measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure). Since $[0,b]$ is the "[almost disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_disjoint_sets)" of $[0,a]$ and $[a,b]$, one has
$$
\mu([0,b]) = \mu([0,a])+\mu([a,b])
$$

---

<sup>$\dagger$Remark. It is worth emphasizing that a key property used here (and also in Martin's answer) is that the singleton $\{a\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero, i.e., $\lambda(\{a\})=0$.</sup>